# SQL Insert from table to table prevented by duplicate primary key from source table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to populate a products table on MySQL with latest products, which are retrieved and stored in products_temp table.
So the method for this is straight forward, simply doing an INSERT to products from products_temp, as such:

```
INSERT INTO products ( select products_temp.* FROM products_temp )
```

Problem is, it results in a duplicate primary key error, because of the id from products_temp clashing with the id in products.

Can someone tell me how to fix this please?

I tried declaring the fields in the select statement without the id, but that results in "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Only insert products from temp who don't currently exists in products???

Comment: How do you want to solve it? Do you want to assign new ids, or skip existing ids? Is the PK an auto num field?

Comment: Doees products_temp include the entire universe of products or just incremental updates?

Comment: products_temp contain a full list of products, the actual select query I have will return the products that are new (not exist in products). The ideal solution will be for the new entries into products to get an autoincremented id, as would be the case if I were to insert a new row directly.

Comment: That is not happening now because we are including the id from products_temp, and if we don't include the id, there is a column mismatch when we try to perform the table copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to declare the columns except the ID on both the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`, since the number of fields need to match, and `id` (as you noticed) can't be inserted as is into the destination table.

```
INSERT INTO DestTable (field1, field2, field3) 
    SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM SourceTable;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fc34e/1).

EDIT: You *could* do it in a bit more hacky way to simplify the insert. You can create a trigger that simply forces the primary key to `NULL` on insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_DT BEFORE INSERT ON DestTable 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.id = NULL;
```

then a copy from table to table can be done as simply;

```
INSERT INTO DestTable SELECT * FROM SourceTable;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c55a/1).

Comment: unfortunately, this seems to be the only way to go about it. Just a little troublesome to list out 46 field names x 2 , was hoping there was a more elegant solution.. :(

Comment: What do you think if I used the scripting language (in this case php) to perform the insert instead? I will still have to declare all the field names (to exlude the id), but only once..

Comment: @Winterain Added an alternative.

Comment: that totally works without many more lines of code! marvelous! Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
INSERT INTO products 
( 
  select products_temp.* FROM products_temp 
  where key not in (select key from products) 
)
```

Comment: nada, that will ignore all rows from products_temp with the conflicting id, but in actual fact all the results in products_temp need to be added.

Comment: I'm guessing that what you're trying to avoid is an insert of an identity column which happens to be the primary key. Your problem statement was that your were trying to avoid a primary key conflict.